# Bandwidth measurement using ping

Tags: ping, bandwidth-measuring

How can I measure bandwidth using ping?  I know I could use something like iperf on each end to do the measurement, but I can't do that because I don't have access to the remote system.  Maybe if I play with the ping size parameter?  Even an estimate will suffice.

Comment: You don't measure bandwidth using ping. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You can't. Ping is used to test reachability. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29

Comment: What I'm trying to do is find out the bandwidth estimate to a given IP.  To any IP.  Its for diagnostic purposes.   Don't understand why this has been marked down.  This is not a stupid question especially since a very good solution exists.  What's even more frustrating is that I accepted the (very good) answer only to have it disappear.

Comment: Yet again, I find myself forced to repeat: *The only thing that ping is a **reliable** test for is whether or not ping works.*

Comment: All I have to say is that the solution does exist.  See in the comments below.  It's called pingb.

Comment: Relevant to professional system administration?  Yes. Very professional.  It's not a stupid question.  The proof is that there is even a solution called pingb.  Questions must demonstrate minimal understanding?  Yes.  Very deep understanding actually.  If you use ping tool in a smart way you can do much more with it than the manual tells you.   Again refer to the (deleted) solution or comments further below. ... Or are we arguing between distinction between "ICMP echo" and traditional "ping" command?  Really?  That silly?

Answer (score 4):

How can you put a nail through a board with a feather? You can't. You need to pick the correct tool for whatever job you have. If you describe in more detail precisely what it is you're trying to do, people can probably tell you what the right tool for the job is.

Comment: Don't know what are you talking about.  I accepted an answer that clearly showed the solution.  I don't know why it's been deleted though.  If you go to http://www.florian.ca/pingb/ you can see for yourself